# VideoCapture display video frame (frontal camera) as 45 degree rotated

Tags: python, video-capture, opencv3.0

I am recording a video with my frontal phone  camera. I try to read it using VideoCapture() opencv on python.

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture("out.mp4")
cv2.namedWindow("CurrentFrame", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
while True:
     ret,currentFrame = video.read()
     cv2.imshow("CurrentFrame", currentFrame)
```

The frame is displayed as 45 degree rotated
Is there anyone got this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Use the function cv2.flip( frame, axis_parameter ) in order to rotate your frame.

```
 cv2.imshow("CurrentFrame", cv2.flip( currentFrame , -1 ))
```

regarding "-1" as parameter I am not sure, you should choose the right parameter.